# timer opens and closes immediately by submitting questions without allowing students to attempt examination

Tags: javascript

Please can anyone help out as the countdown timer on my e-exam just stop working and I couldn't figure out what actually happened... the timer will read zeros (hh:min:sec) and submit student questions automatically without allowing them to answer questions and thereby grade them(students) zero percent. thanks...

```
function countDown() 
{
      sec--;
  if (sec == -01) {
    sec = 59;
min = min - 1;
if(min==-01)
    {
        min=59;
        hour=hour-1;
    }else
        {
            hour=hour;
    }
  } else {
   min = min;
  }
if (sec<=9) { sec = "0" + sec; }



time = (hour<=9 ? "0" + hour : hour) + " : " + (min<=9 ? "0" + min : min) + " : " + sec + "";
if (document.getElementById) { document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = time; }



SD=window.setTimeout("countDown();", 1000);
if (hour=='00'&& min == '00' && sec == '00') { sec = "00";min="00"; window.clearTimeout(SD); window.location=document.forms[0].action+"?fs=yes";}
}

function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
      }
      func();
    }
  }
}

addLoadEvent(function() {
  countDown();
});
```

the php section of the script is this:

```
<?php



error_reporting(0);
session_start();
include_once 'oesdb.php';
$final=false;
if(!isset($_SESSION['stdname'])) {
    $_GLOBALS['message']="Session Timeout.Click here to <a href=\"index.php\">Re-LogIn</a>";
}
else if(isset($_REQUEST['logout']))
{
    //Log out and redirect login page
       unset($_SESSION['stdname']);
       header('Location: index.php');

}
else if(isset($_REQUEST['dashboard'])){
    //redirect to dashboard
    //
     header('Location: stdwelcome.php');

    }else if(isset($_REQUEST['next']) || isset($_REQUEST['summary']) || isset($_REQUEST['viewsummary']))
    {
        //next question
        $answer='unanswered';
        if(time()<strtotime($_SESSION['endtime']))
        {
            if(isset($_REQUEST['markreview']))
            {
                $answer='review';
            }
            else if(isset($_REQUEST['answer']))
            {
                $answer='answered';
            }
            else
            {
                $answer='unanswered';
            }
            if(strcmp($answer,"unanswered")!=0)
            {
                if(strcmp($answer,"answered")==0)
                {
                    $query="update studentquestion set answered='answered',stdanswer='".htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['answer'],ENT_QUOTES)."' where stdid=".$_SESSION['stdid']." and testid=".$_SESSION['testid']." and qnid=".$_SESSION['qn'].";";
                }
                else
                {
                    $query="update studentquestion set answered='review',stdanswer='".htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['answer'],ENT_QUOTES)."' where stdid=".$_SESSION['stdid']." and testid=".$_SESSION['testid']." and qnid=".$_SESSION['qn'].";";
                }
                if(!executeQuery($query))
                {
                // to do
                $_GLOBALS['message']="Your previous answer is not updated.Please answer once again";
                }
                closedb();
            }
            if(isset($_REQUEST['viewsummary']))
            {
                 header('Location: summary.php');
            }
            if(isset($_REQUEST['summary']))
             {
                     //summary page
                     header('Location: summary.php');
             }
        }
        if((int)$_SESSION['qn']<(int)$_SESSION['tqn'])
        {
        $_SESSION['qn']=$_SESSION['qn']+1;

        }
        if((int)$_SESSION['qn']==(int)$_SESSION['tqn'])
        {
           $final=true;
        }

    }
    else if(isset($_REQUEST['previous']))
    {
    // Perform the changes for current question
        $answer='unanswered';
        if(time()<strtotime($_SESSION['endtime']))
        {
            if(isset($_REQUEST['markreview']))
            {
                $answer='review';
            }
            else if(isset($_REQUEST['answer']))
            {
                $answer='answered';
            }
            else
            {
                $answer='unanswered';
            }
            if(strcmp($answer,"unanswered")!=0)
            {
                if(strcmp($answer,"answered")==0)
                {
                    $query="update studentquestion set answered='answered',stdanswer='".htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['answer'],ENT_QUOTES)."' where stdid=".$_SESSION['stdid']." and testid=".$_SESSION['testid']." and qnid=".$_SESSION['qn'].";";
                }
                else
                {
                    $query="update studentquestion set answered='review',stdanswer='".htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['answer'],ENT_QUOTES)."' where stdid=".$_SESSION['stdid']." and testid=".$_SESSION['testid']." and qnid=".$_SESSION['qn'].";";
                }
                if(!executeQuery($query))
                {
                // to do
                $_GLOBALS['message']="Your previous answer is not updated.Please answer once again";
                }
                closedb();
            }
        }
        //previous question
        if((int)$_SESSION['qn']>1)
        {
            $_SESSION['qn']=$_SESSION['qn']-1;
        }

    }
    else if(isset($_REQUEST['fs']))
    {
        //Final Submission
        header('Location: testack.php');
    }
?>
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Examination Platform
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE"/>
    <meta http-equiv="PRAGMA" content="NO-CACHE"/>
    <meta name="ROBOTS" content="NONE"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="oes.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="validate.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cdtimer.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    <!--
        <?php
                $elapsed=time()-strtotime($_SESSION['starttime']);
                if(((int)$elapsed/60)<(int)$_SESSION['duration'])
                {
                    $result=executeQuery("select TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(endtime,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),'%H') as hour,TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(endtime,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),'%i') as min,TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(endtime,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),'%s') as sec from studenttest where stdid=".$_SESSION['stdid']." and testid=".$_SESSION['testid'].";");
                    if($rslt=mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                     echo "var hour=".$rslt['hour'].";";
                     echo "var min=".$rslt['min'].";";
                     echo "var sec=".$rslt['sec'].";";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $_GLOBALS['message']="Try Again";
                    }
                    closedb();
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "var sec=01;var min=00;var hour=00;";
                }
        ?>

    -->
    </script>

    </head>
  <body >
      <noscript><h2>For the proper Functionality, You must use Javascript enabled Browser</h2></noscript>
       <?php

        if($_GLOBALS['message']) {
            echo "<div class=\"message\">".$_GLOBALS['message']."</div>";
        }
        ?>
      <div id="container">
      <div class="header">
                <img style="margin:10px 2px 2px 10px;float:left;" height="80" width="200" src="images/logo.gif" alt=""/><h3 class="headtext"> &nbsp;eExamination </h3><h4 style="color:#ffffff;text-align:center;margin:0 0 5px 5px;"><i>Idea | Innovation | Motivation</i></h4>
            </div>
           <form id="testconducter" action="testconducter.php" method="post">
          <div class="menubar" style="text-align:center;">
              <h2 style="font-family:helvetica,sans-serif;font-weight:bolder;font-size:120%;color:#f50000;padding-top:0.3em;letter-spacing:1px;">Examination Platform</h2>
          </div>
      <div class="page">
          <?php

          if(isset($_SESSION['stdname']))
          {
                $result=executeQuery("select stdanswer,answered from studentquestion where stdid=".$_SESSION['stdid']." and testid=".$_SESSION['testid']." and qnid=".$_SESSION['qn'].";");
                $r1=mysql_fetch_array($result);
                $result=executeQuery("select * from question where testid=".$_SESSION['testid']." and qnid=".$_SESSION['qn'].";");
                $r=mysql_fetch_array($result);
          ?>
          <div class="tc">

               <table border="0" width="100%" class="ntab">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th style="width:40%;"><h3><span id="timer" class="timerclass"></span></h3></th>
                                        <th style="width:40%;"><h4 style="color: #af0a36;">Question No: 1 </h4></th>
                                        <th style="width:20%;"><h4 style="color: #af0a36;"><input type="checkbox" name="markreview" value="mark"> Mark for Review</input></h4></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
             <textarea cols="100" rows="8" name="question" readonly style="width:96.8%;text-align:left;margin-left:2%;margin-top:2px;font-size:120%;font-weight:bold;margin-bottom:0;color:#0000ff;padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;"><?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($r['question'],ENT_QUOTES); ?></textarea>
              <table border="0" width="100%" class="ntab">
                  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                  <tr><td >1. <input type="radio" name="answer" value="optiona" <?php if((strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['answered'],ENT_QUOTES),"review")==0 ||strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['answered'],ENT_QUOTES),"answered")==0)&& strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['stdanswer'],ENT_QUOTES),"optiona")==0 ){echo "checked";} ?>> <?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($r['optiona'],ENT_QUOTES); ?></input></td></tr>
                  <tr><td >2. <input type="radio" name="answer" value="optionb" <?php if((strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['answered'],ENT_QUOTES),"review")==0 ||strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['answered'],ENT_QUOTES),"answered")==0)&& strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['stdanswer'],ENT_QUOTES),"optionb")==0 ){echo "checked";} ?>> <?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($r['optionb'],ENT_QUOTES); ?></input></td></tr>
                  <tr><td >3. <input type="radio" name="answer" value="optionc" <?php if((strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['answered'],ENT_QUOTES),"review")==0 ||strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['answered'],ENT_QUOTES),"answered")==0)&& strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['stdanswer'],ENT_QUOTES),"optionc")==0 ){echo "checked";} ?>> <?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($r['optionc'],ENT_QUOTES); ?></input></td></tr>
                  <tr><td >4. <input type="radio" name="answer" value="optiond" <?php if((strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['answered'],ENT_QUOTES),"review")==0 ||strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['answered'],ENT_QUOTES),"answered")==0)&& strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['stdanswer'],ENT_QUOTES),"optiond")==0 ){echo "checked";} ?>> <?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($r['optiond'],ENT_QUOTES); ?></input></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                  <tr>
                      <th style="width:80%;"><h4><input type="submit" name="<?php if($final==true){ echo "viewsummary" ;}else{ echo "next";} ?>" value="<?php if($final==true){ echo "View Summary" ;}else{ echo "Next";} ?>" class="subbtn"/></h4></th>
                      <th style="width:12%;text-align:right;"><h4><input type="submit" name="previous" value="Previous" class="subbtn"/></h4></th>
                      <th style="width:8%;text-align:right;"><h4><input type="submit" name="summary" value="Summary" class="subbtn" /></h4></th>
                  </tr>

              </table>


          </div>
          <?php
          closedb();
          }
          ?>
      </div>

           </form>
     <div id="footer">
          <p style="font-size:70%;color:#ffffff;"> </b><br/> </p><p></p>
      </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it returns a ReferenceError for sec, min, and hour variable.

You can try to declare a global variable with value on sec, min, and hour variable at the top like the code below and see if it works:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="timer"></div>
<form action="http://stackoverflow.com/">
</form>
<script>
    var sec = 0;
    var min = 1;
    var hour = 0;

    function countDown() 
    {
        sec--;

        if (sec == -01) {
            sec = 59;
            min = min - 1;

            if (min==-01) {
                min=59;
                hour=hour-1;
            } else {
                hour=hour;
            }
        } else {
            min = min;
        }

        if (sec<=9) { sec = "0" + sec; }

        time = (hour<=9 ? "0" + hour : hour) + " : " + (min<=9 ? "0" + min : min) + " : " + sec + "";
        if (document.getElementById) { document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = time; }

        SD=window.setTimeout("countDown();", 1000);
        if (hour=='00'&& min == '00' && sec == '00') { sec = "00";min="00"; window.clearTimeout(SD); window.location=document.forms[0].action+"?fs=yes";}
    }

    function addLoadEvent(func) {
        var oldonload = window.onload;
        if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
            window.onload = func;
        } else {
            window.onload = function() {
                if (oldonload) {
                    oldonload();
                }
                func();
            }
        }
    }

    addLoadEvent(function() {
      countDown();
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks so much dee ronin, after declaring variables, it still doesn't work!

Comment: have you tried debugging the countDown function and see if what is the value of your sec, min and hour variable.

Comment: yes i did, but the its not still working or paraventure i copy the main script so you can have a look if you can come with a solution?

Comment: @epascarello  can you please take a look?

Comment: Please note that the script has been working all this while but just stopped

Comment: I have updated my answer to have the full html and its working if I open in browser (example: chrome). Can you compare in your side the script part? I only added the declaration of sec, min, and hour variable in top of countDown function.

Comment: The code actually works on its on but failed to with this php side it was meant to accompany:

Comment: Not working yet but I have added the php side of the script which the cdtimer.js controls

Answer (score 0):

You could use setInterval() to repeat the seconds countdown if hour, min and sec becomes 0, then redirects to the desired page. Please have a look at the example code I have written. I hope I helped.

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="timer"></div>
<form action="http://stackoverflow.com/"></form>
<script>
    function countDown(){

        //declare and init variables
        var countDown_value = 60, //in seconds
            stopFunction = undefined, 
            countFunction = undefined, 
            date = undefined,
            remainingTime = undefined,
            timer = undefined;


        //main timer
        timer = setInterval(function(){

            //stopFunction and redirect
            stopFunction = function(){
                clearInterval(timer);

                //activate below code to redirect
                //window.location=document.forms[0].action+"?fs=yes";
                document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = "Done"; 
            }

            //countFunction
            countFunction = function(){
                date = new Date(null);
                date.setSeconds(countDown_value);

                remainingTime = date.toISOString().substr(11, 8);
                document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = remainingTime; 
            }

            //check if countDown_value is 0
            countDown_value-- ? countFunction() : stopFunction();       

        }, 1000); //1000 -> repeat every second

    }

    function addLoadEvent(func) {
        var oldonload = window.onload;
        if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
            window.onload = func;
        } else {
            window.onload = function() {
               if (oldonload) {
                   oldonload();
               }
               func();
           }
       }
   }

   addLoadEvent(function() {
      countDown();
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```